# Один функция два элемента

Tags: функции

```
$("#tel") || $("#code").keyup(function(){
    //code
});
```

Как сделать рабочим этот код?
Я хочу получить результат от обоих элементов!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте в функцию список селекторов/классов/id через запятую

```
$("#code, #tel").keyup(function(){
    //code
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но у меня ест один вопрос...

Comment: `$(".regsubmit").bind("click", function(){
    //code
});

$("#tel").keyup(function(){
    //code
});`
Как сделать в одном коде эти два функции...?

Comment: @ZohidJo'rayev например `$('#foo').bind('click keyup', function() { //code });`

Comment: спасибо огромное